# sudo command sudo: /etc/sudoers is world writable sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin

Tags: permissions, sudo

I have run this command by mistake `chmod -R 777 ./*`

Now not able to use sudo and can't open folders as root.

```
sudo: /etc/sudoers is world writable
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

Comment: Where did you run the `chmod` command from?  Were you running this as superuser?  Did you run this from `/`?  We need more information.  THe command as written wouldn't affect the sudoers stuff.

Comment: Try simply entering "chmod 440 /etc/sudoers" on the command line. That should restore your sudo command.